# C# divide two binary numbers

Tags: c#, binary, math

Is it possible in C# to divide two binary numbers. All I am trying to do is:

Get integer value into binary format, see below

```
int days = 68;
string binary = Convert.ToString(days, 2);
```

but how do you divide the binary numbers? , what format should be used?

```
01000100 / 000000100 = 4
```

Little confused any help would be great.

Comment: binary is just a representation... perform the calculation on the int value, not on the binary representation

Comment: Why would you want to divide binary numbers in asp.net?  All division is binary internally... I assume you just want to convert from text binary representation to internal binary representation before dividing?  But why in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to mask the bits together, youll want to use the [& Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c(VS.71).aspx)

```
// convert from binary representation
int x = Convert.ToInt32("01000100", 2);
int y = Convert.ToInt32("000000100", 2);

// Bitwise and the values together
int z = x & y; // This will give you 4

// convert back to binary
string z_bin = Convert.ToString(z, 2);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
// convert from binary representation
int x = Convert.ToInt32("01000100", 2);
int y = Convert.ToInt32("000000100", 2);

// divide
int z = x / y;

// convert back to binary
string z_bin = Convert.ToString(z, 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int a = Convert.ToInt32("01000100", 2);
int b = Convert.ToInt32("000000100", 2);
int c = a / b;
```

and by the way the answer is dec:17 instead of dec:4

Answer (score 2):

it is just:

```
x / y
```

you don't have to convert integer into binary string by

```
int days = 68;
string binary = Convert.ToString(days, 2);
```

numbers are binary in memory.

or i didn't understood you

Comment: Hi guys 

Am trying to do is mask binary values like shown below:

01000100
00000100
--------
00000100

= 4

Comment: @ChrisMogz - See my answer for and'ing two binary values.

Answer (score 0):

This will help u.

```
 namespace BinaryExample1
        {
        class Program
        {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        int i = Convert.ToInt32("01000100", 2);
        int j = Convert.ToInt32("00000100", 2);
        int z;
        z = i / j;
        Console.WriteLine(z);
        Console.ReadLine();
        }
        }
        }
```